# Passing LocalDateTime from one microservice to another as a Post Body parameter

Tags: spring-boot, java-8

I am having an application built on top of Spring boot and Java8. I am trying to pass a LocalDateTime Object from one microservice to another. When I attempt to do so, I get the following error.

```
"JSON parse error: Unexpected token (START_OBJECT), expected VALUE_STRING: Expected array or string.; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unexpected token (START_OBJECT), expected VALUE_STRING: Expected array or string.\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@2930ef8b; line: 8, column: 16] (through reference chain:
```

I have added the below entris to my application.

```
spring:
 jackson:
    serialization:
      write-dates-as-timestamps: false
```

And the following entry in build.gradle.

```
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310'
```

Can anyone help me on what is wrong here?

The POJO looks like this.

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
    private LocalDateTime testDateTime;
```

The JSON looks like this.

```
{ "date_field": "2019-03-27T05:00:00.000Z", }
```

Comment: Well, what does the JSON look like?

Comment: {
 "date_field": "2019-03-27T05:00:00.000Z",

} @Michael

Comment: Are you sure that both your microservices have the same configuration (same dependency, same property, same `@JsonFormat`, ...)? You also seem to be using `date_field` in your JSON, but `testDateTime` in your POJO, is that correct? Also verify if you're creating a custom `ObjectMapper` bean somewhere.

Comment: `LocalDateTime` will never have time zone, parse it to `util.Date`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like that your configuration is wrong. The name in JSON string is "date_field", while your POJO has the property "testDateTime". You should make them convertible by Jackson. Either add an annotation to indicate the field's name is "date_field" (using @JsonProperty)or change the variable name.